# What should I do with a mortgage on mobile home that is in disrepair?

Tags: mortgage

Some years ago I took up payments on a mobile home for a co-worker who was having some money woes.  At the time I was renting and was desiring the opportunity of home ownership myself. To make a long story short I have fallen into hard times, I still have the mobile home, but it has depreciated greatly and needing repairs that will require more than it is worth.  I obtained this in good faith, but now I just don't have the cash flow to repair and continue making payments on something that's not worth it.

How do I get out of this situation?

Comment: Is your name on the note, or is this just an informal agreement with your coworker?

Comment: More details are needed:  How much is the property worth? How much is the note?  What other assets do you have?  What does your credit score look like?  Will you have another place to live?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case of [Sunk Cost Fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_costs). The basic idea is this - don't look at how much you've invested, look at what the thing is worth.

It sounds like you are no longer able to keep up, so the financial answer is to stop making repairs, etc.  The only question is - whose name is on the deed?

If your coworker still owns the asset, you can simply back out say, "the mobile home is yours, any repairs and payments I made are yours too."  Basically, you will be out all of your work and what you put into it, but you're not continuing to dig a hole. Your coworker should consider your investment as a gift, but a gift that is no longer being made.

If in taking over the asset he put it in your name, the asset is yours to do with as you please.  It sounds like you should dispose of the asset, even if its at a loss.

Either way, from a financial perspective, the answer is to cut your losses and be done with it.

All of that is, of course, a strictly financial answer.  Reading between the lines, it seems like you feel guilty about not being able to honor the commitment you have made.  If there is a sentimental attachment to the mobile, I would suggest discussing your situation with the coworker.  That's really not a financial consideration, but that doesn't mean its unimportant.